# Ansible windows firewall rules - Adding many ports from different range under one rule

Tags: windows, ansible, firewall

Recently I did found this ansible module for windows : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_firewall_rule_module.html

There are some examples how to use it and they work for me, but there are either:

1. Adding 1 port for 1 rule (3389)
2. Adding one range of ports for 1 rule (5000-5010)

How to use this module to make a single rule, like this :  3389, 5000-5010?
Or maybe there are other better windows modules for this ?

Comment: If this is s commonly allowed syntax in windows firewall, did you try `localport:  3389,5000-5010`?